# цвет ссылки меняется после нажатия

Tags: html, css

У меня на ссылке стоит якорь, после нажатия происходит плавная прокрутка, но если вернутся к ссылке то её цвет синий, и меняется на белый(цвет который выставил) только по нажатию на любую область страницы. В `body` уже прописал  `vlink="#fff" alink="#fff"`  не помогло. Как исправить изменения цвета?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пора перейти на следующий уровень и использовать CSS.
Скорее всего, ссылка в фокусе. За это отвечает псевдокласс [`:focus`](https://webref.ru/css/focus).

```html
<style>
  body {
    background-color: #333;
  }
  a {
    color: darkorange;
  }
  a:visited, a:focus, a:hover {
    color: #fff;
  }
</style>
<a href="#">Demo link</a>
```